# Entailment relation to derives for specific example

Tags: logic

> Suppose $a, b$ are propositional formulae. If $a \vDash b$ then does $\emptyset \vdash a \implies b$?

This is a bit tricky. But I think it does follow. Since if $a$ is true then $b$ must be true, so we will have $\emptyset \vDash a \implies b$ thus by completeness we can convert this to $\vdash$.

What is a way to "formalize," this?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct: If we're working in classical logic, then $a\vDash b$ exactly if $\varnothing\vDash a\Rightarrow b$, so what you want is true if the proof system you notate as $\vdash$ is **complete**.

You typically wouldn't need to "formalize" this more; it is a completely good argument as written here.

---

Conversely: if your property holds, then your proof system must be either complete or very strange, because we can just take $a$ to be a tautology such as $P\Rightarrow P$. (You could make a weird proof system that only ever proves things whose topmost connective is $\Rightarrow$, in which case it could have your property but not be complete).